# Problem using jQuery UI Accordion and iFrame

Tags: jquery, user-interface, iframe, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm more of a designer than a developer so I'm hoping someone can help me out with this issue. I'm using a jQuery UI Accordion to display content. When all I have is text & links it performs fine. However, I want to showcase video and I want people with iPhones and iPads to be able to see it, so I'm using an iFrame that Vimeo provides to check the user's browser & OS and dynamically deliver the video in HTML 5 or Flash.

The jQuery UI Accordion and iFrame works great on desktop browsers (although a little clunky of FF), but when I test it on my iPhone and iPad it doesn't work. Basically the first item is visible and usable, but the minute I try to select another item it looks like it's hiding the content. Check it out [here](http://tonangi.com/portfolio_web_test.html). You'll see that it works fine on a desktop browser, but it's broken on iPhones and iPads. If you don't have an iPhone or an iPad to look at it here is an [image](http://tonangi.com/images/bug_ipad.jpg)

As you can see all of the content is hidden. The accordion still animates when I click on the 2nd item but none of the content is visible.

Here is what I'm using in my head

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/south-street/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
```

Here is what I'm using in my body

```
<td width="626"><div id="jQueryUIAccordion" >
    <h3><a href="#">The Skin Spa</a></h3>
    <div>


<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/7691842?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="540" height="304" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        <p class="TM-Font1"><a href="http://www.skinspanewyork.com/" target="_new">The Skin Spa</a>,  skin treatment center, wanted to inform their customers on some of the most popular procedures being performed and what they entailed. Tonangi Design &amp; Media created 5 separate movies that are showcased on their website as well as on flat screen televisions in their spa locations. <strong>View the rest of the videos that we produced for the Skin Spa</strong>: <a href="port_photolight.html"path/to/pop-page.htm" target="page" onClick="window.open('','page','toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=640,height=400,left=0,top=0,titlebar=no')">Photolight</a>    | <a href="port_skint.html"path/to/pop-page.htm" target="page" onClick="window.open('','page','toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=640,height=400,left=0,top=0,titlebar=no')">Skin Tightening</a>| <a href="port_hair.html"path/to/pop-page.htm" target="page" onClick="window.open('','page','toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=640,height=400,left=0,top=0,titlebar=no')">Hair Removal</a> | <a href="port_micro.html"path/to/pop-page.htm" target="page" onClick="window.open('','page','toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=640,height=400,left=0,top=0,titlebar=no')">Microdermabrasion</a></p>
<p class="TM-Font1"><strong>&gt; <a href="portfolio_comm.html">Check out our TV &amp; Web commercials</a></strong></p>
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#">Hook Up Your Dorm</a></h3>
    <div>

    <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/9719129?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="540" height="304" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        <p class="TM-Font1"><a href="http://www.hookupyourdorm.com/" target="_new">Hook Up Your Dorm</a> needed to explain their unique service to their customers. Since the bulk of their users would be high school students about to move into a college dorm, the web video had to be concise yet descriptive. The video is used on their website today.</p>
<p class="TM-Font1"><strong>&gt; <a href="portfolio_comm.html">Check out our TV &amp; Web commercials</a></strong></p>
    </div>
```

**Notes:** At first I was using the code right off of Google, but I thought there may have been a bug so I went and tried to get the latest and greatest.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<style type="text/css">
@import url("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/south-street/jquery-ui.css");
```

Any help at all would be extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

iPhone and the iPad both use WebKit as their Rendering Engine.

So there should absolutely be little to no difference wether you are testing this on iPhone/iPad or Safari browser.

**I was unable to reproduce this issue.**

Comment: Well that was my thought as well, but obviously that's not the case.What's funny is that the content is actually there, but it's hidden. I didn't even know it but I just was pinching and zooming to see if it had any affect. (I'm grasping at straws here). And I heard the audio for the video. It's here - it's just hidden!